# How do I take contents of a file and to move it to another in batch script?

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am trying to made a batch script that the user types in the two file names they want to merge and then leaves them with a merged file. I already made it merge I just need to know how to copy the contents of the first file and enter it into a variable to add to the second file.

Here is what I have so far

```
@echo off
set /p firstfile=
set /p secondfile=
echo %firstfile% >> %file%
```

I just need %firstfile% to be contents of the variable firstfile

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are asking. Check if this helps.
If you want to keep the contents in a variable and then copy the content from the variable to the second file you can do this.

```
@echo off
set /p firstfile=
set /p secondfile=

set /p content=<%firstfile%
echo %content% >> %secondfile%
```

In this code, `set /p content=<%firstfile%` copies the contents of the first file into the variable content, and `echo %content% >> %secondfile%` appends the contents of content to the second file.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: This copies _one line_ from firstfile to secondfile, IF that line does NOT contain any `<>|&^` character(s)